# Apache Redirect without include document root in rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, redirection, documentroot

I have this working rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp/$ https://example.com/$1?amp=1 [QSA,R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

For redirecting `https://example.com/register/amp/` to `https://example.com/register?amp=1`.

And it is working well, but I would like that the URL in the browser didn't change so it will load the `register?amp=1`, but in browser still show `/register/amp/`.

To achieve this behaviour, I try modifying to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp/$ ./app.php/$1?amp=1 [QSA,R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

But then it redirects to `https://example.com/home/user/public_html/register?amp=1`.

So it is adding the document root wrongly and I don't know how to modify the rule to achieve that.

Comment: Have you looked into "%{REQUEST_URI}"? check here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070635/rewriting-url-to-hide-real-page-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp/$ ./app.php/$1?amp=1 [QSA,R=301,NC,NE,L]
> ```

You need to remove the `R` (external "redirect") flag. The `./` prefix on the *substitution* string is also superfluous here and just adds complexity that the OS must optimise out.

When you specify a relative path *substitution* in a directory context (`.htaccess` or `<Directory>` container in the server config) and you have not stated an alternative prefix (or "base" directory) with the `RewriteBase` directive, then Apache adds back the directory-prefix (ie. `/home/user/public_html/` in this case) at the end of the rewriting process. It is because this is an external redirect that you are exposing this directory-prefix in a malformed redirect. You need an internal rewrite instead.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp/$ app.php/$1?amp=1 [QSA,NC,NE,L]
```

However, you've also included `app.php` in the *substitution*, which you've not shown in your target URLs? (`app.php` maybe correct - you should be rewriting to the actual *filesystem* path and not rely on any additional rewrites or subrequests by mod_dir.)